# Correlation used as explanatory device in ''The neuroscience of Intelligence'

Tags: measurement, methodology, statistics, iq, correlation

I am currently reading Dr. Richard Haier's book The Neuroscience of Intelligence. I have a base knowledge of statistics, but I am confused about the following extract from page 80 (chapter 2.4):

> When correlations are computed in identical twins reared apart, the
>   correlation is  also one way to estimate heritability, so a
>   correlation of .70 indicates that 70% of the  variance in intelligence
>   is due to genetic factors and 30% is not.

Is using correlation a valid way to estimate the heritability of a specific trait? I was under the impression that for a comparison of shared variance r² would have to be used, which would mean IQ is not 70% inherited, but only 49% (a huge difference!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is simply not being explicit. The

> correlation

is neither *r* or *r*<sup>2</sup>, it is simply the relation between x and y.

[Pearson's correlation coefficient, or *r*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) is a measure of the linear correlation between two variables. It's value is between +1 and −1, 1 being a total positive linear correlation, 0 means no linear correlation, and −1 is total negative linear correlation.

The [coefficient of determination, or *r*<sup>2</sup>](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/coefficient-of-determination-r2) has a value between 0 and 1. A value near 1 indeed indicates that most of the variation of the response data is explained by the different input values, whereas a value of *r*<sup>2</sup> near 0 indicates that little of the variation is explained by the different input values.

Now to your book; 70% seems indeed like a lot. I thought it was approximately 40% and this is backed up by [NIH](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/traits/intelligence) and [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/is-intelligence-hereditary/) that mention approximately 50%. However [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritability_of_IQ) mentions numbers up to 86% and back this statement up with influential articles. [(Plomin & Deary, 2015)](https://www.nature.com/articles/mp2014105) indeed postulate that

> The heritability of intelligence increases from about 20% in infancy to perhaps 80% in later adulthood.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Plomin & Deary, *Molecular Psychiatry* (2015); **20**: 98–108](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/traits/intelligence)</sub>

Comment: Ah okay, so he used 'correlation' not as a statistical term, but as a therm for expressing that there is an association between the variables?

Comment: @toljoas - I reckon; I don't know the book, but from the context you can deduce what he means; if he isn't talking about p values, but only holds a monologue in popular scientific terms, he just means 'relation between x and y'.